# XML INSERT INTO Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, parameter-passing

I wish to populate a SQL table with a single call using an XML param string.

My code to build the XML follows :

Loop through the list

```
' update string for reserved character (ampersand) 
Dim descStr As String = allMarkets(0).result(j).event.name.Replace("&", "&&amp;")
(NOTE : the ampersand reference text shown is not displaying correctly in this browser, where I put the correct string reference it is displaying incorrectly)

strBuffer.Append(" <ID>""" & allMarkets(0).result(j).event.id.ToString & """ </ID><DESC>""" & descStr & """</DESC>")

Next
```

My stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[PriceDataXMLEVENTInsert1]
    (@ValidXMLInput XML)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PRICEDATA (EventID, EventDesc)
       SELECT 
           x.v.value('@ID', 'INT'), 
           x.v.value('@DESC', 'nvarchar(50)') 
       FROM 
           @ValidXMLInput.nodes('//ROOT/ROW') x(v)
```

The XML string passed to the function holds valid data and the code runs fine... but when there should a few hundred records in the table `PRICEDATA` - there are none..... what is wrong with the above...?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer...

G

Comment: Can you provide us with the actual string being passed to the stored procedure?

Comment: I did try to .. but because it is XML itself when I attmped to post earlier it displayed incorrectly , Its a long string, so here a piece of it...

<ROOT> <ID>"27748379" </ID><DESC>"Garbarnia v KS Spartakus Daleszyce"</DESC> <ID>"27748239" </ID><DESC>"H Petach Tikva Youth v H Rishon Lezion Youth"</DESC> .....</ROOT>

Comment: If I simply insert a single value with an XML string to match.. this ....


ALTER PROC [dbo].[PriceDataXMLEVENTInsert](@ValidXMLInput XML)
AS BEGIN
 
       INSERT INTO PRICEDATA(EventID)
       SELECT Col.value('@ID','INT')
       FROM @ValidXMLInput.nodes('//Events/Event') Tab(Col)
 
END

works fine...

Comment: Can you put up the full string on Pastebin?

Comment: You try to query your data as attributes (with `@ID`) but you build your XML with your data as elements (`<ID>value</ID>`). You make it even worse when you put your values in `"` signs...

Comment: In your example data the ID value is the same for both rows. Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your original question: What is wrong with

```
SELECT x.v.value('@ID','INT'), x.v.value('@DESC','nvarchar(50)') 
FROM @ValidXMLInput.nodes('//ROOT/ROW') x(v)
```

Your sample data do not show a `ROW` element, neither are there attributes `@ID` or `@DESC`. This will return nothing...

#### A solution for your bad data

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<ROOT>
    <ID>"27748379" </ID>
    <DESC>"Garbarnia v KS Spartakus Daleszyce"</DESC>
    <ID>"27748239" </ID>
    <DESC>"H Peta8h Tikva Youth v H Rishon Lezion Youth"</DESC>
</ROOT>';
```

There are several flaws:

- Do not separate your elements this way. Use either `<element><ID>gfjha</ID><DESC>sfasdf</DESC></element>` to bind them together (both within one node), or - what would be my choice - use `<element ID="fasdf" DESC="fsdfdaf">`
- If you put your values in attributes (`<element attr="value">`) you need the quotation marks. But in elements they are disturbing!
- If you want to escape characters you must at least escape the < with `&lt;` the > with `&gt;` and the & with `&amp;` (**no doubled &&** as in your example!)

Anyway, this was a way to get table like data out of your XML to have an easy insert. But you really should change your structure!

```
WITH IDNodes AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr
          ,B.value('.','varchar(max)') AS ID
    FROM @x.nodes('/ROOT/ID') AS A(B)
)
, DESCNodes AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr
          ,B.value('.','varchar(max)') AS [DESC]
    FROM @x.nodes('/ROOT/DESC') AS A(B)
)
SELECT IDNodes.ID,DESCNodes.[DESC]
FROM IDNodes 
INNER JOIN DESCNodes ON IDNodes.Nr=DESCNodes.Nr
```

The result (you should let the `"` away...)

```
ID          DESC
"27748379"  "Garbarnia v KS Spartakus Daleszyce"
"27748239"  "H Peta8h Tikva Youth v H Rishon Lezion Youth"
```

#### And finally this is what you probably really wanted to achieve:

```
DECLARE @ValidXMLInput XML=
'<ROOT>
    <element ID="27748379" DESC="Garbarnia v KS Spartakus Daleszyce"/>
    <element ID="27748239" DESC="H Peta8h Tikva Youth v H Rishon Lezion Youth"/>
</ROOT>';

SELECT A.B.value('@ID','int') AS ID
      ,A.B.value('@DESC','varchar(max)') AS [DESC]
FROM @ValidXMLInput.nodes('/ROOT/element') AS A(B)
```

Comment: Shnugo - thank you for your prompt response! 
The prposed solution works a treat.. I take on board what you say about my bad coding structure.... I used to code SQL Server many many years back  .... so have forgotten much and getting back into these things can take some time... particularly as the grey matter gets less inclined...! THANKS AGAIN, a great help.